# Biblatex-apa, adherence to standard apa formatting of date (full date vs. year only)

Tags: biblatex, formatting, memoir, apa-style, zotero

I use Zotero for my manage my bibliography. Zotero lets me export my library in both BibLateX and BibTeX formats. There is not much difference between them, however, I did notice that it exports the year for a given reference differently.

If I have specified the exact date for a reference, e.g., 1991-09-01, exporting in "biblatex" format includes the full date, whereas, in BibTeX format, it includes the year and month separately, and excludes the day (see below):

```
BIBLATEX
@article{mysampleref_1991,
    [...]
    date = {1991-09-01},
    langid = {english}
}

BIBTEX
@article{mysampleref_1991,
    [...]
    month = sep,
    year = {1991},
    pages = {339--354}
}
```

Now, as such, that is not a problem. However, according to APA, a standard journal article in the Bibliography should only show the year (not the full date, with month and day) after the author.

I use biblatex-apa in my preamble as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{reflib.bib}
```

If I import my bib file with the biblatex formatted bib file, which has the full date, the reference in my bibliography will also show the full date (see screenshot below). I am surprised by this behaviour as I would have thought that biblatex-apa would automatically suppress the full date and only show the year, but it does not. I have to additionally specify in the package options  `labeldate=year` to make sure only the year appears. Surely, biblatex-apa would adhere to standard APA by default?

[image]

As requested here a basic MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{biblatex.bib}
\begin{document}
Just a basic test of some an APA reference \cite{wheeler_self-recording_1991}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and here the contents example of the exported bibliography from Zotero in biblatex-format (biblatex.bib)

```
@article{wheeler_self-recording_1991,
    title = {Self-recording of everyday life events: origins, types, and uses},
    volume = {59},
    issn = {1467-6494},
    url = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-6494.1991.tb00252.x/abstract},
    doi = {10.1111/j.1467-6494.1991.tb00252.x},
    shorttitle = {Self-Recording of Everyday Life Events},
    abstract = {Some abstract text},
    pages = {339--354},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Personality},
    author = {Wheeler, Ladd and Reis, Harry T.},
    urldate = {2017-04-07},
    date = {1991-09-01},
    langid = {english}
}
```

Comment: Which versions of biblatex and the APA style are you using? Can you also give a complete MWE we can try? It is possible that you are using an older version of the style from before this issue was fixed.

Comment: @plk I can replicate this with the most recent versions of `biblatex` (3.7) and `biblatex-apa` (7.4).  The language mapping (`american` or `british` doesn't matter either.)

Comment: Thanks, Alan and PLK, this is on sharelatex and they are using as Alan suggested biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 and apa.dbx 2017/01/06 v7.4 APA. For convenience, I'll put together a basic MWE.

Comment: MWE added above.

Comment: You have to ping people with an at symbol e.g. @PLK.

Comment: But you can only ping one person per comment, so @AlanMunn must be pinged in a new comment.

Comment: thanks @cfr, learned something new and guess you pinged them for me in that case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in version 7.5 but it's not released yet. As a workaround for now, you can add this to your preamble:

```
\AtEveryCite{%
  \clearfield{labelmonth}%
  \clearfield{labelday}%
  \clearfield{labelendmonth}%
  \clearfield{labelendday}%
}
```

Comment: We will probably have to wait for the OP to confirm that, but I *think* she also wants the month and day gone in the bibliography.

Comment: Given what I could find at http://research.moreheadstate.edu/c.php?g=107001&p=695198 and probably more importantly http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/01/the-generic-reference-when.html maybe you could automate `month` day `deletion` for most types except for the exceptions listed in the links.

Comment: BTW: Regardless of what was actually wanted, don't you need `\AtEveryCitekey` in order to access entry fields? Deleting fields in `\AtEveryCite` should not work.

Comment: @PLK thank you for the suggested workaround, unfortunately as @moewe suggested, adding `\AtEveryCite{%` with the `clearfields` into the preamble does not remove month and day from the Bibliography, which is what I was reporting. The in-text citing is and was okay. As mentioned in my original post, adding the option `labeldate=year`as an option, like this `\usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true, labeldate=year]{biblatex}` will remove month and year from the Bibliography. My post was more in regard to me wondering why I should need to do this? But good to hear you are now aware and working on it.

Comment: @moewe, btw I also tried using `\AtEveryCitekey`, but that makes no difference for the Bibliography.

Comment: @Tina Of course not, `\AtEveryCitekey` is still for citations. For the bibliography you would need `\AtEveryBibitem` instead.

Comment: @moewe, ok thanks, wasn't thinking ... yes, `AtEveryBibitem` works fine. Any reason why I should rather use that with the respective clearfields, instead of adding the general package option?

Comment: @Tina Actually, I would use `labeldate=year`. There is one catch with that though, the links in my comment above indicate that in a few rare cases the APA wants to see full dates. With `labeldate=year` it is hard to get the full date back, while with the `\clearfield` approach it is easy to do that conditionally on entry type or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this issue when I updated biblatex (3.9)  and biblatex-apa (7.5) with Miktex on Windows 10. For the bib entries I use Zotero with BBLatex export tool.

I used to have the `date= year` package option and :

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
```

Replacing `month` by `labelmonth` and `day` by `labelday` solved the problem. It is confusing as `month` and `day` are not fields in the bib entry.